# How to do greedy match in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Not sure if this is greedy or not, but wondering how to do this. I want to:

- match any string (including any `+`, `?`, or `*`)
- if it has a `+`, `?`, or `*` at the end, then keep that information

So here are some example inputs and desired outputs:

```
match("foo+"); // ["foo", "+"]
match("1+2"); // ["1+2"]
match("a+b+"); // ["a+b", "+"]
match("a*b?"); // ["a*b", "?"]
match("some+really+long+string+"); // ["some+really+long+string", "+"]
```

Here is the pattern I tried but it just matches the whole string:

```
var s = "\\d+";
var p = /(.+)([\+\*\?])?$/;
p.match(s); // ["\d+", "\d+", undefined]
```

Basically I just want to parse out the operators (`*+?`) from a possible regular-expression-like string. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you only trying to remove the operators on the end of a match?

Comment: Yeah. I mean you could do it other ways like `str.substr(str.length - 1)` type thing, but wondering if there is a way to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: Why use regex? What about `x = string[string.length-1]; x == '?' || x == '*' || x == '+'`

Comment: This may interest you. The performance of regexp is most often slower than a simple replace or char check like @meagar mentioned above. Check out the following link and see for yourself. http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial match needs to be non-greedy, and you need to anchor the regex

```
var s = "\\d+";
var p = /^(.*?)(\+|\?|\*)?$/;

s.match(p); // ["\d+", "\d", "+"];
```

Note that, if your comment ("I basically want to just strip of the last character if it's *+?") is actually accurate, regex is a terrible tool for this job.

Use `s[s.length - 1]` to get the last character.

Comment: Why is regexp a terrible tool for this job just so I know?

Comment: Because you don't need to match a pattern. You need to get the last character. Using regex for this purpose is massive over-kill, and introduces a huge amount of complexity for a very simple task.

Comment: `^(.*?)([+?*])?$` is more elegant, IMO.

Comment: Ah, probably should have described further what I was doing. I am matching a pattern in my situation, and was doing it the substr way before but it added a lot of code. Seeing if a regexp simplifies it. https://github.com/grammarjs/grammar/blob/master/lib/symbol.js#L18-L19

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, then you probably want

```
var arr = str.match(/([\w\+\?\*]+\w)([\w\+\?\*]?)/)
```

The first element in the array is the whole match. If you want only the submatches, take `arr.slice(1)`.

Comment: mmm this isn't quite it, I basically want to just strip of the last character if it's `*+?` using a regular expression. This requires a certain form of the preceding text.

Comment: It looks like it's what you get for all your test cases, no ? But maybe you have other cases in mind ?

Comment: What form of preceding text, @Lance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^(.+)([+*?])$|(.+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iB3gX6/1)**

[image]

This will match:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `foo`
2.  `+`
MATCH 2
1.  `1+2`
MATCH 3
1.  `a+b`
2.  `+`
MATCH 4
1.  `a*b`
2.  `?`
```

So, the idea is to have a pattern that captures:

```
^(.+)([+*?])$  ---> the content and also everything that finish with a +, * or ?
|(.+)          ---> or... all the content
```

Using this you will cover both cases, those with finish with `+`,`*`or`?` and the others